# What is the connection between norminv and normrnd?

Tags: matlab

If I just want to calculate a standard normal variable is there any difference between using:

```
samples=norminv(rand(N),0,1);
```

and

```
samples=normrnd(0,1,N,1);
```

Either in terms of processing time or convergence when used in a Monte Carlo simulation?

The reason I ask is that I want to use a quasi Monte Carlo technique like Halton numbers with `norminv()` to replicate `normrnd()`, but first I want to make sure I understand the relationship between them.

I guess one of the central questions is: how are the random numbers are generated in `rand()` and `normrnd` respectively? Is it the same method?

If they are entirely equivalent why the duplication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both approaches give the same distribution, by the [theorem of inverse transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) (as you surely know). One important difference, though, is computation time:

```
N = 1e6;

tic
samples = norminv(rand(N,1),0,1);
toc

tic
samples = normrnd(0,1,N,1);
toc

tic
samples = randn(N,1);
toc
```

gives

```
Elapsed time is 0.171892 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.039265 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.029649 seconds.
```

So, even Matlab probably uses uniform random numbers internally to generate Gaussian random numbers, its implementation is more efficient in terms of speed than doing `norminv(rand(...))` yourself.

Why is `rand` faster than `normrnd`? Because `normrnd` is just `rand` preceded with some input checking, and also, as noted in [@chappjc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21319943/2586922), lets you specify mean and standard deviation (but you don't seem to need that). (You can see `normrnd` source code by typing `open normrnd`).

Bottom line: I would use `randn`.

Comment: Good refresher and pertinent link. +1 It's interesting that MATLAB functions continue to use `randn` despite recommending `rnd` in all the documentation. Personally, I find `rng` tedious to use. However, note that `normrnd` uses `randn` rather than `rand`.

Comment: @chappjc I'm too old for `rnd` :-) I started with `rand` / `randn` and have never moved away from them

Answer (score 2):

You get a *uniform* distribution with `rand`, and a *normal* distribution with `randn`.

Now, if the question is what is the relationship between `normrnd` and `randn`, the answer is that `normrnd` is a convenience function that takes the mean and standard deviation of the distribution as input arguments.  That is, `normrnd` does the following:

```
r = randn(sizeOut) .* sigma + mu;
```

As for `normrnd` (using `randn`) vs. `norminv` (using `rand`), see Luis Mendo's answer (it will be the same distribution). And as I noted, you can skip `normrnd` entirely with the equation above.

Comment: +1 I forgot that `normrnd` lets you specify mean and std. I have incorporated that to my answer